# Get ListView item position by uri / by the data it contains

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

I have a ListView which I populate using a custom CursorAdapter.
Now I want to manually update just one specific item in the ListView. I have the content URI of that item. Is it possible to use just this info to get the position of the item in the listView?
If I have the position I can do something like

`View v = mListView.getChildAt(itemPosition - mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition());`

to update the view. But how can I get itemPosition?

I know that I get the position in the onItemClickListener, but I need to update the view without it being clicked.

Any help guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListView` does not support updating a single position.

You must update the adapter with the new data (even if you change a single position) and the, invoke `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

If you get the `View` by its position (via `listView.getChildAt()`) will work. However, if you scroll up and down the list, that view will display the old data again because the adapter is not aware of the change (and it is the adapter which update the view contect view `getView()`).

When you invoke `notifyDataSetChanged()`, you are telling to the adapter that your data set has new info and the `ListView/Adapter` will re-draw the visible items (it won't re-draw whole list at once.. only the visible items).

You may want to consider to change to `RecyclerView` in the future. The `BaseAdapter` used in a `RecyclerView` support actions such as add/remove/update a single position.

Comment: Hm. My version with `View v = mListView.getChildAt(itemPosition - mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition());` seems to work though once I have the position. But since I can't get `itemPosition` in a clean way, I will probably take your advice at some point and migrate to RecyclerView. Thanks!